# Configure Application Toolbar

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, e4

I want to customize the application toolbar to my own needs. A long time ago I played around (and did some impressive customizations) with  the [`AbstractPresentationFactory`](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Findex.html&org/eclipse/ui/presentations/AbstractPresentationFactory.html).

However this extension point was removed and replaced with... not sure, the documentation states it's `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme`, but I don't see how that extension point helps my cause at all.

I managed to guess my way into implementing a solution that makes my texts blue:

*plugin.xml*

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme">
   <theme basestylesheeturi="content/test.css"
          id="myFirstTheme"
          label="My First Theme" />
</extension>

<extension id="application" point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
   <product application="org.acme.project" name="Project">
      <property name="cssTheme" value="myFirstTheme" />
   </product>
</extension>
```

*test.css*

```
Text {
    color: COLOR-CYAN;
}
```

Now what? How do I configure the main toolbar using that mechanism? Is there any documentation how the CSS file should look like and what can be configured? Or any kind of rule?

(Since Google only shows "Hello World" examples and source code, I assume there is yet again no documentation. In that case the precise problem I'm facing is: I want to make toolbar buttons bigger and add text below the image.)

Comment: I found some documentation that doesn't help with this problem, but might help the next sap who tries to use this "feature": [SWT Mapping](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/CSS/SWT_Mapping)

Comment: You would probably have to use a [renderer factory](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Renderer/article.html) for the tool bar for this.